# How to find space complexity for anagram question

Tags: c++, arrays, time-complexity, space-complexity, anagram

I use two 26 element arrays in my program.
What is the time and space complexity for this program to find if a string is an anagram of another?

```
int arr1[26] = { 0 };
int arr2[26] = { 0 };

for (char& x : s)
arr1[x - 'a']++;

for (char& x : t)
arr2[x - 'a']++;

for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    if (arr1[i] != arr2[i])
        return false;
}
return true;
```

Comment: what is `s`, what is `t`, if you want to calculate the big O notation of a variable `n` then what is `n`? is it the size of `s`, the size of `t`, or is it in respecct to the array size?

Answer (score 3):

In the answer below I assume `n` is the total length of the input, i.e. `s.length() + t.length()`.

**Space complexity:**
You require 2 arrays of 26 elements (`int`s in this case).
Since this is a constant that does **not** depend on the input size, the **space complexity is O(1)**.

This is of course in addition to the space required to store the input itself (O(n) assuming it is all in memory).

**Time complexity:**
The first 2 loops will traverse the input once. For each element you do a constant number of operations (incrementing a counter in an array). Therefore their time will be O(n).
The last loop has a constant time that does **not** depend on the input size (26 iterations). Therefore it is O(1).
Together the **time complexity is O(n)**.